# How to use PHP_EOL without \n and br

Tags: php, oop

I tried to use `PHP_EOL` without `\n and <br/>` .But this getting output same line.it's not going to new line.my PHP version is 5.5 . i'm not echo inside the function i used return .i tried both of these.but same problem.This is the Example i tried.

```
trait FooTest
{
    public function sayFoo()
    {
        return "I 'a'm saying Foo with Trait".PHP_EOL;
    }
}


trait BarTest
{
    public function sayBar()
    {
        return "I 'm Saying Bar with Trait".PHP_EOL ; 
    }
}

class TraitTest
{
    use FooTest,BarTest;

    private $property = " Hello there ";

    public function getVal()
    {
        return $this->property ;
    }
}

$trait = new TraitTest;

print $trait->getVal();
print $trait->sayFoo();
print $trait->sayBar();
```

Comment: To get a line break in HTML, you need `<br>`, not a normal "\n" or `PHP_EOL`. This has nothing to do with OOP, it's just how HTML works.

Comment: You mean you echo "\r\n" to website and don't see line break? Maybe because it's ignored by browser, only "<br/>" will produce new line on website.

Comment: Have it write to a file, and you'll see that the values will be on seperate lines. Other than viewing on screen, use the tags.

Comment: You could do ob_start(); $data = ob_get_clean(); and then echo nl2br($data); to convert all newlines to <br/> if you want to view it from browser.

Comment: ```PHP_EOL``` is used to make linebreaks IN THE SOURCE CODE. It has nothing to do with the html rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine, right click your browser and select 'view source' and you will see the raw output, complete with line breaks

If you want to see line breaks in your browser, you need to use html (eg `<p>` or `<br>` tags)

Answer (score 0):

The constant `PHP_EOL` should generally be used for output only.so what ever you have written is correct.to see line break on html you can use `<br>`.